# How to configure views path depending on domain name?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running my express.js app under few domain names. Depending on domain, I'd like to use different views:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views', template));
```

I was trying to use middleware to define template variable, but it seems' that it needs to be done in a different way, because node app says, that template is undefined.

```
var domainConfig = function (req, res, next) {
  if(req.get('host') == 'domainA') {
      template = 'one';
  } else { 
      template = 'two';
  }
  next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't declaring your variable before assigning it a value, nor are you attaching it to a variable you could access later.  You could reword something like this:

```
var domainConfig = function (req, res) {
    if(req.get('host') === 'domainA') {
        res.template = 'one';
        return;
    } 
    res.template = 'two';
}
```

Then later in the cascade, you can refer to `res.template` to see which you are using, and use it to set a template path or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I already resolved my problem using:

```
res.render(path.join(__dirname, '../views', res.template 'viewname'), {...}
```

However, there's a problem with static files. I define them in app.js, before request:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'templatename'));
```

Is this another way to do it AFTER request, when I know which domain is in use?